# How do I get the sum of radio button values by changing the values with regex?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, radio-button

I want to add the values of all the radio buttons clicked but the numbers I am getting aren't correct.

```
<div id="config">
    <input type="radio" name="brand" id="dell" value="Dell $1500"> Dell
    <input type="radio" name="brand" id="mackbookpro" value="MacbookPro $3000"> Macbook Pro
    <input type="radio" name="brand" id="asus" value="Asus $2000"> Asus

    <input type="radio" name="ram" id="4gb" value="4 Gb $60"> 4 GB RAM
    <input type="radio" name="ram" id="8gb" value="4 Gb $90"> 8 GB RAM
    <input type="radio" name="ram" id="16gb" value="4 Gb $125"> 16 GB RAM

    <input type="radio" name="storage" id="250gb" value="250 Gb $100"> 250 Gb Storage
    <input type="radio" name="storage" id="500gb" value="500 Gb $200"> 500 Gb Storage
    <input type="radio" name="storage" id="900gb" value="900 Gb $300"> 900 Gb Storage
</div>

<div id="show">0</div>
```

And the jQuery looks like this

```
var displayPrice = document.getElementById('show');

$("#config input[type=radio]").click(function() {
    var total = 0;
    $("#config input[type=radio]:checked").each(function() {
        var checked = $(this).val();
        var checkNum = checked.split('$')[1];
        total += parseFloat(checkNum);
    });
    displayPrice.innerHTML = total;
});
```

The math I am getting doesn't add up correctly.Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you're continuously adding instead of resetting the value each time.

Comment: What is the `dediPrice` variable?

Comment: Your code is fine http://jsfiddle.net/66f4ay9L/ Maybe dediPrice has unexpected value?

Comment: I actually meant to take the dediPrice variable out. I just edited it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tweaked it a little bit, seems to be working alright:

```
$("#config").click("input[type=radio]",function() {
    var total = 0;

    $(this).parent().find('input[type=radio]').each(function() {
        var self = this;

        if(self.checked){
            total += parseFloat(self.value.split('$')[1]);
        }
    });

    alert(total);
});
```

[Here is a jsFiddle for it](http://jsfiddle.net/6awfkep0/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like adding a string `dediPrice` to the numeric `total` results a string.

To be sure it works convert `dediPrice` to numeric as well:

```
var dediPrice = parseFloat(document.getElementById('show').innerHTML);
```

See the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/66f4ay9L/1/

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine. The math adds up perfectly. Just a few suggestions:

1. **change** instead of **click** event
2. **this.value** instead of **$(this).val()**
3. **+checked.split('$')** and do away with **parseFloat**

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/4oLtky3j/)

```
$(function() {
    var displayPrice = $('#show')[0];
    $("#config input[type=radio]").on('change',function() {
        var total = 0;
        $("#config input[type=radio]:checked").each(function() {
            var checked = this.value;
            var checkNum = +checked.split('$')[1];
            total += checkNum;
        });
        displayPrice.innerHTML = total;
    });
});
```